# Porting Windows Phone HyperlinkButton Navigation To Windows 8 HyperlinkButton Navigation

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I'm porting one of my Windows Phone 8 apps to Windows 8 and I'm having a navigation issue.

Windows Phone 8 C#:

```
HyperlinkButton flcb_standard = new HyperlinkButton();
flcb_standard.NavigateUri = new Uri("/player.xaml?publishingpoint=http://mlmidev.webcastcenter.com/flcb_1/idev.isml/manifest", UriKind.Relative);
```

Windows 8 C#:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(player), publishingpoint);
```

I can bind a control to the appropriate command, in XAML, with `Click=""`.  The problem is that I'm creating the control with C# and I haven't found a property that I can set `this.Frame.*` to.

How can I perform this navigation, using the new Windows 8 navigation methods?

Comment: There is Command property and Click event, however I'm not sure about it. I think that you can't assign navigation directly to HyperLink control, but you can try to do it via event or command functions and navigate from the code after catching event/command.

Comment: If that would work, I'd have to be able to pass the publishingpoint variable from the main page, through an event function, and then to the player page.  That's the big issue (the query string).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I'm not sure if this is the best way of doing it.  It does work, though.

c#:

```
// set outside of the other two functions so it will be global
string publishingpoint_sunday = "";

public async void Rebroadcast()
{
    publishingpoint_sunday = rootObject.sunday_publishingpoint_smoothstreaming;

    HyperlinkButton sunday_title = new HyperlinkButton();
    sunday_title.Content = "Sunday (" + sunday.ToUpper() + ")";
    sunday_title.Click += sunday_link_Click;
}

private void sunday_link_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(Player), publishingpoint_sunday);
}
```

So, there you have it.  The new Windows 8 style of navigation.  To me, it seems unnecessarily complicated.